# Struggling with iterating through dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, element

I'm a newbie to Python, and have done my absolute best to exhaust all resources before posting here looking for assistance.  I have spent all weekend and all day today trying to come up with what I feel ought a straightforward scenario to code for using two dataframes, but, for the life of me, I am spinning my wheels and not making any significant progress.

The situation is there is one dataframe with Sales Data:

```
CUSTOMER  ORDER   SALES_DATE  SALES_ITEM_NUMBER  UNIT_PRICE  SALES_QTY
001871    225404  01/31/2018  03266465555        1           200
001871    225643  02/02/2018  03266465555        2           600
001871    225655  02/02/2018  03266465555        3           1000
001956    228901  05/29/2018  03266461234        2.2658      20
```

and a second dataframe with Purchasing Data:

```
PO_DATE       PO_ITEM_NUMBER  PO_QTY  PO_PRICE
01/15/2017    03266465555     1000    1.55
01/25/2017    03266465555     500     5.55
02/01/2017    03266461234     700     4.44
02/01/2017    03266461234     700     2.22
```

All I'm trying to do is to figure out what the maximum PO_PRICE could be for each of the lines on the Sales Order dataframe, because I'm trying to maximize the difference between what I bought it for, and what I sold it for.

When I first looked at this, I figured a straightforward nested for loop would do the trick, and increment the counters.  The issue though is that I'm not well versed enough in dataframes, and so I keep getting hung up trying to access the elements within them.  The thing to keep in mind as well is that I've sold 1800 of the first item, but, only bought 1500 of them.  So, as I iterate through this:

For the first Sales Order row, I sold 200.  The Max_PO_PRICE = $5.55 [for 500 of them].  So, I need to deduct 200 from the PO_QTY dataframe, because I've now accounted for them.

For the second Sales Order row, I sold 600.  There are still 300 I can claim that I bought for $5.55, but, then I've exhausted all of those 500, and so the best I can no do is dip into the other row, which has the Max_PO_PRICE = $1.55 (for 1,000 of them).  So for this one, I'd be able to claim 300 at $5.55, and the other $300 at $1.55.  I can't claim for more than I bought.

Here's the code I've come up with, and, I think I may have gone about this all wrong, but, some guidance and advice would be beyond incredibly appreciated and helpful.

I'm not asking anyone to write my code for me, but, simply to advise what approach you would have taken, and if there is a better way.  I figure there has to be....

Thanks in advance for your feedback and assistance.
-Clare

```
for index1,row1 in sales.iterrows():
    SalesQty = sales.loc[index1]["SALES_QTY"]
    for index2,row2 in purchases.iterrows():
        if (row1['SALES_ITEM_NUMBER']==row2['PO_ITEM_NUMBER']) and (row2['PO_QTY']>0):
           # Find the Maximum PO Price in the result set
               max_PO_Price = abc["PO_PRICE"].max()

            xyz = purchases.loc[index2]
            abc = abc.append(xyz)
    
           if(SalesQty <= Purchase_Qty):
              print("Before decrement, PO_QTY = ",??????? *<==== this is where I'm struggle busing****)
              print()
    +index2
    #Drop the data from the xyz DataFrame
    xyz=xyz.iloc[0:0]

    #Drop the data from the abc DataFrame
    abc=abc.iloc[0:0]
+index1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like something SQL would elegantly handle through analytical functions. Fortunately Pandas comes with most (but not all) of this functionality and it's a lot faster than doing nested iterrows. I'm not a Pandas expert by any means but I'll give it a whizz. Apologies if I've misinterpreted the question.

Makes sense to group the `SALES_QTY`, we'll use this to track how much QTY we have:

```
sales_grouped = sales.groupby(["SALES_ITEM_NUMBER"], as_index = False).agg({"SALES_QTY":"sum"})
```

Let's group the table into one so we can iterate over one table instead of two. We can use a `JOIN` action on the common column `"PO_ITEM_NUMBER"` and `"SALES_ITEM_NUMBER"`, or what Pandas likes to call it "merge". While we're at it let's sort the table categorised by `"PO_ITEM_NUMBER"` and with the most expensive "PO_PRICE" on the top, this is and the next code block is the equivalent of a `FN OVER PARTITION BY ORDER BY` SQL analytical function.

```
sorted_table = purchases.merge(sales_grouped, 
                            how = "left",
                            left_on = "PO_ITEM_NUMBER",
                            right_on = "SALES_ITEM_NUMBER").sort_values(by = ["PO_ITEM_NUMBER", "PO_PRICE"], 
                                                                        ascending = False)
```

Let's create a column `CUM_PO_QTY` with the cumulative sum of the `PO_QTY` (partitioned/grouped by `PO_ITEM_NUMBER`). We'll use this to mark when we go over the max `SALES_QTY`.

```
sorted_table["CUM_PO_QTY"] = sorted_table.groupby(["PO_ITEM_NUMBER"], as_index = False)["PO_QTY"].cumsum()
```

This is where the custom part comes in, we can integrate custom functions to apply row-by-row (or by column even) along the dataframe using `apply()`. We're creating two columns `TRACKED_QTY` which is simply the `SALES_QTY` minus `CUM_PO_QTY` so we know when we have run into the negative, and `PRICE_SUM` which will eventually be the maximum value gained or spent. But for now: If the `TRACKED_QTY` is less than 0 we multiply by the `PO_QTY` else the `SALES_QTY` for conservation purposes.

```
sorted_table[["TRACKED_QTY", "PRICE_SUM"]] = sorted_table.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x["SALES_QTY"] - x["CUM_PO_QTY"], 
                                                                              x["PO_QTY"] * x["PO_PRICE"] 
                                                                              if x["SALES_QTY"] - x["CUM_PO_QTY"] >= 0 
                                                                              else x["SALES_QTY"] * x["PO_PRICE"]]), axis = 1)
```

To handle the trailing `TRACKED_QTY` negatives, we can filter the positive using a conditional mask, and `groupby` the negative revealing only the maximum `PRICE_SUM` value.
Then simply append these two tables and sum them.

```
  evaluated_table = sorted_table[sorted_table["TRACKED_QTY"] >= 0]
evaluated_table = evaluated_table.append(sorted_table[sorted_table["TRACKED_QTY"] < 0].groupby(["PO_ITEM_NUMBER"], as_index = False).max())

    evaluated_table = evaluated_table.groupby(["PO_ITEM_NUMBER"], as_index = False).agg({"PRICE_SUM":"sum"})
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: You are absolutely amazing.  I'm sorry I did not reply sooner, but, as I was so exhausted I ended up sleeping for quite some time.  When I woke up and saw your reply, I was both amazed and overwhelmingly grateful for your invaluable assistance.  Truly, thank you so much for your reply.  You really are incredible, and I am humbled by your selflessness to take time out of your day to assist a total stranger.  Many, many thanks to you.  -Clare

Comment: Hi @apw-ub:  You greatly assisted me yesterday, but, I'm still struggling with something, and I know you could probably figure this out in about 20 minutes.  I got a little lost with your explanation, and I posted this question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64462898/struggling-to-remove-rows-from-my-dataframe

If you could be so kind as to take a look and advise, I would be more than happy to purchase an Amazon gift card for your terrific assistance.  Thanks!

Comment: I haven't enough points to post a comment so I'll do it here. If you've created the final table you can insert a conditional into the square brackets. E.g. `sales[sales["SALES_QTY"] == 0]` which means that if `SALES_QTY` is zero then remove it. You can also chain them with `(condition1) & (condition2)`. The conditional returns a boolean True and False mask and pandas returns only the rows that are True. Is this in line with what you're looking for? (Thanks for the kind gesture but it's really no problem! A lot here help out because we really enjoy what we do :) )